# .htaccess rewrite but it get wrong parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

That's my link

```
A.http://domaim/category/para1
B.http://domaim/category/para1/
C.http://domaim/category/para1/para2
D.http://domaim/category/para1/para2/
```

paramater is a string (urlencode or others)

and that's my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)$ category.php?mid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ category.php?mid=$1&sid=$2
```

A and C get right parameter,but B and D get page no found!! Error 404

then I try to modify .htacess but it wrong

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?mid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/(.*)$ category.php?mid=$1&sid=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ending "/" too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)([/]{0,1})$ category.php?mid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)([/]{0,1})$ category.php?mid=$1&sid=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the rules you first used, but add `/?`to the end, just before `$`. This makes the trailing slash optional.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1&sid=$2
```

---

**Recommendation:** For the purposes of preventing duplicate content, it's probably a better idea to trim trailing slashes from the URI first:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# If not a directory, then trim trailing slashes ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Then handle rewrites ...
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)$ category.php?mid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ category.php?mid=$1&sid=$2
```